# Two Mac Apps: why does one run in my Mac and in VMWare 5 VM ,while the other runs on Mac only?

Tags: macos, vmware, fusion

Mountain Lion, VMWare Fusion 5
Hardware: MacBook Pro Core 2 Duo
Software: Mountain Lion and VMWare Fusion with second version of 10.8 installed in virtual machine

I have two Developmental Mac OS X apps, App1 and App2.
App1 and App2 both run normally on my Mac. App1 run also
in VMWare Fusion, App2 does not run in the virtual machine.

Where do I look for clues for why App 2 will not run in VM?

Comment:
When I run the Console app I get three message following a double-click on App2's icon in the VM.

8/26/13 2:40:11.221 AM usbmuxd[12385]: AMDeviceStartSession (thread 0x100581000): Could not start session: kAMDInvalidHostIDError
8/26/13 2:40:11.221 AM usbmuxd[12385]: _AMDevicePreflightWorker (thread 0x100581000): Pair worker could not pair with device 16: 0xe8000082
8/26/13 2:40:11.221 AM com.apple.usbmuxd[12385]: HandleDeviceAttachHelperCallback preflighting failed for WiFi device 0x10-192.168.1.252:0: 0xe8000082. Ignoring device.

Safari runs fine in the VM.
The first line sounds like it could be due to ta lack of the UUID from the virtual machine in the profile.
In my attempts to get App2 running I have used two different profiles. The profiles are 
identical except that for one I added the VM UUID and the other I did not.

It is puzzling to me that App1's profile has no UUID for the virtual machine and runs well anyways.

Many Thanks, Mark

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was all my fault. App1 does not support iCloud. App2 does. My goof was the following. I had enabled iCloud on my Mac but not on the VMWare virtual machine. Like any physical machine I needed to turn on iCloud on in the Settings of the OS X virtual machine.
Mark